# Ways to connect 2 buildings via networking

Tags: network

I am not really sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

I have an assignment in which it gives the following scenario.

There're 2 buildings A and B. The distance between building A and B is 800 meters.

The tricky part of this question is that between building A and B where they're separated, there's a natural obstacle such as river/lake.

I have did some research and I found out the following.

1. Use antenna and radio receiver (w/wo signal booster)
2. Use sky cabling.

Is there any other ways or devices that need to be used or applied?

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resources, see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Classwork and education questions are, sadly, off topic here.  There's a big difference between a obstacle like a lake and an obstacle like a hill or thick trees.

Comment: How do people get across the river? one generally wouldn't directly connect two buildings unless the same company is using both. put the cable under the bridge.

Comment: You must have a site survey with specifics because each situation requires different methods, some of which may be restricted or controlled by government regulation or other factors. There is no single answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really quite simple:

- 800 m distance mandates either fiber or a suitable wireless, directional technology (802.11, WLL, microwave, laser, ..) which would need to be explored on site (line of sight, Fresnel zone, climate, ...).
- You need to either go around, under, over or through any obstacle. If you cannot do it yourself you might be able to rent a line from someone who can (dark fiber, Metro Ethernet, MPLS, ...).
- Depending on your exact requirements, a *virtual* link might also work, ie. procure Internet access on each location and create a VPN.

Answer (score 3):

Wireless or wired means that account for the obstacle(s). Those are the options. Details are up to your research or imagination. There are many wireless options that can reach beyond 800 meters, same for wired (fiber optic mostly) solutions. For the issues of the lake or river, you can run cables under water.

Comment: ... and for a lake, there might be an option to go around - single-mode fiber is good for 10-100 km.